# Need to resolve "Cannot find name 'Cy'."

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, cypress

I need to resolve this error "Cannot find name 'Cy'.", related to Cypress. [Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dDwH.png)

I have tried a couple of already shared solutions but they are not helping can someone please guide me here?

Comment: Had the same issue. Adding `"types": ["cypress"]` to my `compilerOptions` in my `cypress/tsconfig.json` file resolved it.

Answer (score 10):

As I see, you are using TypeScript here. Try to go through [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support). Do you have `tsconfig.json` in your `cypress` folder? If so, maybe you just need to restart your IDE.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response here, I had `tsconfig.json` inside my cypress folder with the required configs as per docs but unfortunately still same error.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help without seeing the whole structure and files. Maybe try to create a new project with `npx create-next-app@latest --typescript --example with-cypress with-cypress-app`, check if that works and if so then you can compare files and configs.

Comment: Thanks mark, Restarting my IDE(Intellij) worked.